# Promise with Async Ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to make multiple async Ajax calls and want to do some action when all ajax calls are completed. So I am trying to use jquery promise functionality, but it seems like it is calling $.done function before the ajax calls are successful.

Below are my codes:

```
    pool = {a: 1, b: 2};
    for(var camp in pool){
        promises.push(parseFile(camp));
    }

    $.when.apply($, promises).done(function() {
        console.log("All jobs finished");
    });

    function parseFile(fname)
    {
        console.log(fname +" call");
        $.ajax({
            url: "data/" + fname + ".txt",
            dataType: "text"
        })
        .done(function(data) {
            console.log(fname + " done");
        });
    }
```

**Console Log:**

a call
b call
All jobs finished **// THIS SHOULD HAVE BEEN CALLED AT THE END**
a done
b done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`parseFile` need to return a promise other wise the value returned by the method will be undefined, which will be considered as the `$.when()` as a resolved value.

```
function parseFile(fname) {
    console.log(fname);
    //return the ajax promise here
    return $.ajax({
        url: "data/" + fname + ".txt",
        dataType: "text"
    })
        .done(function (data) {
        console.log(fname + " done");
    });
}
```

Comment: I have been searching solution for last 3 hours !! Thanks a lot !